# What is the command to access my user details in Mongo shell?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongo-shell

I obviously do have a user in my local copy of my MongoDB database.

I went to the appropriate database via `use server_users`, but when I do `db.getUsers()`, I get an empty array.

But when I run this in my `node` REPL:

```
> Buffer.from(session, 'base64').toString('utf8')
'{"passport":{"user":"5ad25c401dfbaee22188a93b"}}'
```

You can clearly see I do have a user in my Mongo database.

How do I pull up that user in my mongo shell?

This is my `passport.js` file:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

// passport.use() is a generic register to make Passport
// aware of new strategy
// creates a new instance to authenticate users
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
      proxy: true
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

      if (existingUser) {
        // we already have a record with given profile id
        done(null, existingUser);
      }
      // we dont have a user record with this id, make a new record
      const user = await new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
      done(null, user);
    }
  )
);
```

Comment: Do you mean MongoDB users used for authentication to MongoDB, or a `users` collection that is storing user accounts for an application?

Comment: By the content shown the question actually means *"the passport authentication details stored in a collection"*, which is of course NOT what `db.getUsers()` has anything to do with since that refers to *"MongoDB access control and authentication"* which is not part of the *"application users"*. So the data is contained within the collection that was named in the "passport" settings for the application. You "get users" by simply doing a `find()` on the appropriate collection.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thank you for jogging my memory. I don't write Mongo shell queries as much as I would like to. Please go ahead and post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1

```
> show dbs
    admin         0.000GB
    auth          0.000GB
    local         0.000GB
    muber         0.000GB
    seed_data     0.000GB
    server_users  0.000GB
    upstar_music  0.004GB
    users_test    0.000GB
```

Step 2

```
> use auth
switched to db auth
```

Step 3

```
> db.getCollection('users').find({}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cedf41999c20922fd05cdce"),
    "email" : "test123@example.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$Yu194aPMrwuA6JZStTwu7OmaAugFNM1XvXDDBVpF1d5wKKHaPmLFe",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceee2237d1b22dfbf37820f"),
    "email" : "test99@example.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$.a9jWOSQbLG32lInCCUwGeqZDM9ksbTN7MDMo1kbOaApmMUr3cCLO",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceeeb02d35e4ee61d602040"),
    "email" : "test919@example.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$fSq31UO/4IEPMaXzgIHXK.zlMO8IUPsVh4Vf9MRo7zldk9dSgiwVS",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceeee0bd72c8ae85dcbbc7f"),
    "email" : "test900@example.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$l/99bU2MpElHhVFNXk1tB.k69DOAcdc/ySuek33MjtjAB0yLTqAqi",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ceef1cddf3064eaf8530f68"),
    "email" : "test901@example.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$aKzilNGIm9HZx0iSXhsvbe9UCFqNt5FWjVd7T.GX7uKawAfCyG3JS",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cef25fc43a429ec05759849"),
    "email" : "test902@example.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$JY0w/UuvT4Ub7T3RR9.VVOIH6V4RX9bTwoWzwEBbTiidPEiasakNq",
    "__v" : 0
}
```